# Finding number of tangents to a circle using homogenization

Tags: calculus

> The equation of circle $x^2 + 2gx + 2fy + y^2 =c^2$ , find the pair of tangents from origin.

For applying the result on page-108 of this Differential calculus for beginners by Joseph Edwards [(here)](https://archive.org/details/differentialcal03edwagoog/page/n126/mode/1up), I homogenize the equation:

$$ x^2 + 2gxz + 2fyz + y^2 - c^2 z^2=0$$

And then I take partial with $z$

$$ 2gx + 2fy -2c^2 z=0$$

Or,

$$ gx +fy -c^2 z=0$$

Setting $z=1$

$$ gx +fy -c^2=0$$

This would suggest that there is only one tangent from the origin when there are possible with two tangents from origin.. but that's not always the case, there maybe a tangent pair. So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: There may also be no tangent if the origin is inside the circle.

Comment: I mean that's fine but I took the equation of a genreal circle @CiaPan

Comment: As I showed below ,this situation makes sense only if the circle passes through the origin, that is if $c=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2+2 f y+2 g x=c^2\tag{1}$$

The equation of the circle $(1)$ can be written as
$$(x+g)^2+(y+f)^2=c^2+f^2+g^2\tag{2}$$
The center of the circle is $C(-g;\;-f)$ and the squared radius $r^2=c^2+f^2+g^2$

The squared distance from the center to the origin is
$CO^2=g^2+f^2$ therefore we have

$CO^2=g^2+f^2 <r^2$ that is, the origin is internal and so zero tangents, unless $c=0$ which means that the circle passes through the origin.

TL;DR

To have a tangent passing through $O$ must be $c=0$.

So $(1)$ becomes
$$x^2+y^2+2 f y+2 g x=0\tag{1'}$$
A line through the origin has equation $y=mx$

it is tangent to the circle $(1')$ if the equation
$$x^2+(mx)^2+2f(mx)+2gx=0$$
$$\left(m^2+1\right) x^2 +2x (f m+ g)=0\tag{3}$$
has a double root. That is if the discriminant of $(3)$ is zero.

which means
$$(fm+g)^2=0\to m=-\frac{g}{f}$$

The tangent equation is
$$y=-\frac{g}{f}\,x\to gx+fy=0$$

**Edit**

If the point is external, then the line we get intersects the circle in the tangent points, as the book you have linked says "the $(n-1)th degree curve *passes through the points of contact of the tangents*"

If the circle is $(x-5)^2+(y-3)^2=1$ and we follow the procedure we get the line $5 x + 3 y=33$ as you can see in the picture below.

In the second picture I draw a more intriguing example. I leave to you  the  details.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you , this was clear but it'd be of massive help if you could point the error in my derivative calculation because I can't seem to figure out if there is an exception of the identity for this case or if I made mistake in application

Comment: @Buraian I have massively edited my answer to explain the reason why must be $c=0$. There is no mistakes in your calculation, simply $c=0$ since the beginning.

Comment: What if origin is outside the circle itself @Raffaele?

Comment: It cannot be. It can be internal or on the circumference. Never external. It depends on the way the equation is written. @Buraian

Comment: Consider the circle $(x-5)^2 + (y-3)^1 =1$ ,now origin is outside circle and I still get only one tangent from the point  from the theorem in book, however all internet sources that I can find says , there should be at least two tangents from a point to circle

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope it will explain better. @Buraian

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I had misunderstood the theorem but the diagram made it all completely clear @Raffaele

Answer (score 0):

As the book says, you need to calculate partial derivatives $f_x, f_y, f_z$ of your $f(x,y,z)$ function (with a homogenizing variable $z$ added) and plug *them* as 'coefficients' to obtain the equation of a tangent: $$X\,f_x+Y\,f_y+z\,f_z=0$$
Of course, the equation will have parameters $x,y$ in it, which are coordinates of the point of tangency.

What you did is taking $f_z=0$ with $z=1$.

Comment: Ok I think I got the my mistake, but still I ended up with only one tanget line